# Is it possible to detect if the Data Connector runs in Power BI Desktop or Service?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I would like to detect if my Data Connector runs in Power BI Desktop or Service. I would like to include this information in the web requests for telemetry.

Answer (score 0):

if the connector was created by you, you can add some get parameter on the url and recognise that this request was done from connector .
source = Web.Contents(url & "?client=connector"),

you can dont add on service  nothing  and just look  if exist client param in your get it mean  the request was done from connector else service